# Adding UIImage in Subview and Adding Constraints - Image does not resize

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, swift4

I am trying to add an image in my sub view and then add in constraints and resize it.

When i set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true then my image resizes perfectly but my constraints don't work. When I set to false, my constraints work but my image size is regular size and won't size down.

Here is example.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxRBk.jpg

```
let image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: 31,
                                 height: 29)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true


        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addConstraints([


            // FIRST AVATAR

                    // leading
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
                               attribute: .leading,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view,
                               attribute: .leading,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 28),

                    // top
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
                               attribute: .top,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view,
                               attribute: .top,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 6),

                    // bottom
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView,
                               attribute: .bottom,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view,
                               attribute: .bottom,
                               multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 5)

            ])
```

My Error:

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2821c3700 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x12da069a0.midX == 15.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2821d4410 H:|-(28)-[UIImageView:0x12da069a0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x12da067c0 )>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the **trailing** constraint. You've only set **leading**, **top**, **bottom** constraints so far.

And if you want to use Auto Layout (let leading, top, bottom, trailing constraints work), keep `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`.

Comment: Are you try to set your image at position {x: 28, y: 6} with size {width: 31, height: 29} with Auto Layout constraints?

Comment: I set the constraints height and width and now it works!! Thank you